# Как сделать так чтобы приложение разработанное на Unity , запускалось в горизонтальном положении на телефоне?

Tags: android, unity3d-android

Делаю приложение в горизонтальном виде, на телефоне запускается в вертикальном, как это можно исправить?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-orientation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заходишь в `File`, `Build Settings`, `Player Settings`, вкладка `Resolution and Presentation`, пункт `Default Orientation` и выбираешь какая ориентация экрана тебе нужна.